# Adjusted predictions running ANOVA in Stata

Tags: stata, anova

I have an outcome variable `x` and three explanatory variables `a, b, c` which are categorical variables. In my example `a` has 8 levels, `b` has 4 levels and `c` has 35 levels, but not all combinations of the three variables has observations (this is probably unimportant).

If I run the following additive ANOVA model in Stata

```
anova x a b c
adjust, by(a b) gen(y)
```

then I obtain predictions of the variable `x` adjusted by the variables `a` and `b`. The adjust command outputs the following table in the Result window, and also it generates a variable `y` with adjusted predictions.

---

```
      |                 b                 
    a |       2        4        8       16
----------+-----------------------------------
   50 | .016655  .018487                  
   75 | .008286  .011237                  
  100 | .005937  .006677  .012467         
  150 | .001905  .004038  .009454         
  200 | .001774  .003107  .007592  .010081
  400 |          .004982  .006853  .009342
  800 |                   .002126   .00521
 1000 |                   .002732  .005221
----------------------------------------------
 Key:  Linear Prediction
```

My problem is that the variable `y` has a value for each combination of `a, b` and `c` while the table above only has values for each combination of `a` and `b`. How can I save the results from the table, so I'm able to work with these? What is the connection between the values in the table and the values in `y`?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**: I found this in `help adjust`:

> Variables used in the estimation command but not included in either the by() variable list or the adjust variable list are left at their current values, observation by
>       observation.  Here adjust displays the average estimated prediction (or the corresponding probability or exponentiated prediction), substituting the mean of these unspecified variables within each group defined by the variables
>       in the by() option.

This is also true for my data. For example if `a=75` and `b=2`, then `c` takes on the values 12,13,14,15,16. The value of `y` corresponding to `c=14` (which is the average) is exactly what is displayed in the table. But what if the average of the values is not a value that it takes on?

Comment: The average of a set of values need not be one of those values. Stata is showing conditional predictions, not echoing the data.

Comment: Exactly, but how do I go about getting the predicted value for the averages of `c`? The table leaves nothing in the return list, so I guess I have to use the "gen" options with adjust. But using "gen" as I stated leaves only predictions for the original values.

Comment: Switch to `margins`. `adjust` still works, but it has been superseded by `margins`. (If you have an out-of-date version of Stata, then you won't have `margins`, but it is a good idea to flag which version you have in postings here.)

Comment: I'm using Stata/SE 12.1. But `adjust, by(a b)` doesn't yield the same result as `margins a#b`. Shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a reply to Stefan Hansen's comment on `adjust` and `margins`.

In general, no; but everything depends on the model and whether there are covariates other than those named. But consider the results of

```
sysuse auto, clear 
anova mpg foreign rep78
adjust, by(foreign rep78)
margins foreign#rep78
```

Here the results do coincide.

I am not fluent in `margins` beyond elementary uses, so any more complicated questions will need to be handled by someone else.